# Java key - key map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, bidirectional

I need a kind of map which is accessible in two directions, so with a key-key structure instead of key-value. Does this exist in Java? If not, what is the best way to create it?

So example:

```
mySpecialHashMap.put("key1", "key2");

mySpecialMap.getL2R("key1") returns "key2";
mySpecialMap.getR2L("key2") returns "key1";
```

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670038/does-java-have-a-hashmap-with-reverse-lookup

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So you want a bidirectional map. You can use [Apache Commons Collections BidiMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html) or [Google Collections BiMap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap) for this.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [BiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) from the [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library (formerly known as Google Collections).

An example where a [HashBiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html) is used as the "mySpecialHashMap":

```
BiMap<String, String> myBiMap = HashBiMap.create();
myBiMap.put("key1", "key2");

myBiMap.get("key1"); // returns "key2"
myBiMap.inverse().get("key2"); // returns "key1"
```

Comment: If someone's not using Guava yet: it's totally sweet and you probably should. See [this post (and comments)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/132639/56285) for some great learning resources.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is [BiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) from Google Collections.

Answer (score 1):

Or for reversible enums see [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582940/should-i-be-trying-to-create-a-reversible-enum-in-java-or-is-there-a-better-way).