# Sequence number of an enumeration litteral in Java

Tags: java, enumeration

Given the following definitions:

```
public enum SampleEnum1 { Uno, Dos, Tres }
public enum SampleEnum2 { One, Two, Three, Four }
```

I need two methods doing this:

- Given the integer 2, return `Dos` if applied to `SampleEnum1`, `Two` if applied to `SampleEnum2`
- Given the value `One`, return `1`

In fact I need to translate an enumeration litteral into its sequence number in the enumeration definition, and vicae versa.

I don't mind using generics, reflexion, or whatever, as long as the same 2 methods work for any enumeration.

Do you have the solution?

Comment: This has been answered over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021246/conveniently-map-between-enum-and-int-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use a helper method like

```
public static <E etxends Enum<E>> E lookup(Class<E> eClass, int number) {
     return eClass.getEnumConstants()[number-1];
}

SampleEnum1 se1 = lookup(SampleEnum1.class, 2);
```

BTW: You could start with Zero which would simplify your code as well.

Comment: Thank you, what i was looking for. And `ordinal()` is the opposite function I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you can be sure to keep your enums in order in the source file, you can do like this to get the enum by number:

```
public static SampleEnum1 getSpanishEnum(int index) {
    return SampleEnum1.values()[index - 1];
}

public static SampleEnum2 getEnglishEnum(int index) {
    return SampleEnum2.values()[index - 1];
}
```

And to go the other way, you can do a loop

```
public static <E extends Enum> getEnumIndex(E value, E[] values) {
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if(value == values[i]) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

calling it like this:

```
getEnumIndex(SampleEnum1.Dos, SampleEnum1.values());
```

Answer (score 1):

The forward direction can be done using the `Class.getEnumConstants()` method:

```
  public static <E extends Enum<E>> E getValue(Class<E> eClass, int index) { 
      return eClass.getEnumConstants()[index - 1];
  }
```

Called as follows:

```
  SampleEnum2 two = getValue(SampleEnum2.class, 2);
```

(Unfortunately, we can't write a generic method that uses the `values()` method that every `enum` has.  It is static so we can't access it by polymorphic dispatching.  To access it reflectively we'd need to know the actual class of `E` ... and that requires a `Class<E>` object.  And if you have to pass that, you may as well call its `getEnumConstants` method.)

---

The reverse direction is simpler:

```
  public static <E extends Enum<E>> int getIndex(E e) { 
      return e.ordinal() + 1; 
  }
```

Of course, it is much neater if you follow the normal IT convention that the indexes of a collection start from zero.