# Java cast Long to Enum type issue

Tags: java, casting, enums, long-integer, primitive-types

I had a little problem with casting Java long type to Enum type and can't find a solution how to do that.

Here is what I'm using :

```
public enum DataType {
    IMAGES(1),
    VIDEOS(2);

    private int value;
    private DataType(int i){
        this.value = i;
    }
}
```

and I need to do  something like this:

```
DataType dataType;
String thiz = "1";
long numb = Long.parseLong(thiz);
dataType = numb;
```

The error that I get says:

> *Convert numb to DataType or convert dataType to long.*

**Second Scenario:**

I have this :

```
static String[] packetType;
String tmp=incomingData.toString(); // where incomingData is byte[]
int lastLoc = 0;
int needsSize = packetFieldSizes[tmpCurrentField-1]; // where packetFieldSizes,tmpCurrentField are integers.
thiz=tmp.substring(lastLoc, needsSize);    

packetType=thiz;  // packetType = thiz copy; where thiz is the same as used above.
```

I tried to convert thiz to String[] and use valueOf,but

Any suggestions how to get the thinks to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't have more than about 30K enum values which makes `long` or even `int` overkill for what you need.

Comment: so you recommend me to use int instead of long?

Comment: it's unclear what you refer to with "I tried to convert this to String[] and use valueOf".

Comment: Also note that `String tmp=incomingData.toString(); // where incomingData is byte[]` is prone to errors due to encoding mismatch. Use `new String(byte[],charsetName)`

Comment: Sorry,it has to be I tried to convert thiz to String[].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Enum` already provides a unique integer for each of it's instances. Check out [`ordinal()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29). (Note that it's zero-based though.)

If you need to go from a `long` to a `DataType` you can do

```
DataType dataType;
String thiz;
long numb = Long.parseLong(thiz);
dataType = DataType.values()[(int) numb];
```

A complete list of conversions from and to enum constants, strings and integers can be found in this answer:

- [Conveniently map between enum and int / String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021246/conveniently-map-between-enum-and-int-string/5021384#5021384)

Comment: Having your own `id` for every enum constant is imho a good practise in scenarios where you have this IDs persisted, since `ordinal()` may change for the same item when you insert new constants in between.

Comment: To get rid of a warning, you should use a cast: `DataType.values ()[(int) numb];` and I guess VIDEOS as a result for 1L is unexpected.

Comment: right. I updated the answer regarding the cast. Yes, if one indeed need a 1-indexed sequence, a `numb-1` is needed.

Comment: Actually I just updated my answer...can you look at the second scenario.

Answer (score 5):

If for some reason you need to assign the numbers yourself and thereby can't use aioobe's good solution, you can do something like the following:

```
public enum DataType {
    IMAGES(1),
    VIDEOS(2);

 private final int value;
 private DataType(int i){
    this.value=i;
 }
 public static DataType getByValue(int i) {
     for(DataType dt : DataType.values()) {
         if(dt.value == i) {
             return dt;
         }
     }
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("no datatype with " + i + " exists");
 }
```

The static method `getByValue()` searches for the `DataType` with the provided number.

Comment: I just updated my question.Any ideas how to make it work for second scenario?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [@aioobe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230252/java-cast-long-to-enum-type-issue/7230291#7230291), you could roll your own `getInstance` method. This would provide more flexibility, since you wouldn't be dependent on the ordinal.

```
public enum DataType {
    .
    .
    public static final DataType getInstance(final int i){
        for(DataType dt: DataType.values()){
            if(dt.value == i){
                return dt;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer from aioobe. Maybe some other concerns ?

You could be better of using int instead of long, for the enum index.
It could be like :

```
String indexAsString;
int index = Integer.parseInt(indexAsString)-1;
DataType dataType = DataType.values()[index];
```

Please note the "-1", as arrays are zero-based while your index is one-based.

Answer (score 1):

ordinal() will work if the numbers you are passing to the enum are indexes and not some arbitrary code, like resolution or number of chars in a line.

I'd extends the enum with an accesor method for the value, a resolution index and a static method that resolves a number into a Enum value. Here you go...

```
public enum DataType {
       IMAGES(1),
       VIDEOS(2);
    private int value;

    DataType(int i){
       this.value=i;
    }

    static final Map<Integer,DataType> inverseIndex;
    static {
        inverseIndex = new HashMap<Integer,DataType> ();
        for (DataType dt:DataType.values()) {
            inverseIndex.put(dt.getValue(), dt);
        }   
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static DataType resolve(int number) {
        return inverseIndex.get(number);
    }
}
```

Note that this solution won't work is your map Enum-value is not bijective, so you may only have distinct values for the enums in your enumType.