# Android: How to Switch on Runnable in Message Queue?

Tags: android, handler, message-queue, runnable

I have searched the java API on Thread, [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#handleMessage%28android.os.Message%29), [HandlerThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html), Looper , as well as SO, and cannot find an answer.  Of course, I have also used Eclipse's debugger to step and inspect my 'msg'.

**Situation:** If you protect your data model from concurrency issues by allowing only one worker thread to have access to it, how would you then differentiate between a Runnable versus a Message in its `handleMessage(Message msg)` if you were enqueueing both Messages and Runnables in the same message queue?

**Q.** While my Runnables execute as planned after being posted via `handler.postDelayed(myRunnable)`, I would like to inspect the contents of the Runnable while my worker thread is switching upon it so that I can update my data model appropriately.

**I welcome all feedback and appreciate your time!**

Below is the entire contents of 'msg' as shown from Eclipe's debugger.  Is there even enough information here to switch on the Runnable?

```
msg Message  (id=830030887816)  
    arg1    0   
    arg2    0   
    callback    null    
    data    Bundle  (id=830030968104)   
        mAllowFds   true    
        mClassLoader    BootClassLoader  (id=830023329296)  
            packages    HashMap  (id=830023329320)  
            parent  null    
        mFdsKnown   true    
        mHasFds false   
        mMap    HashMap  (id=830030980304)  
        mParcelledData  null    
    flags   1   
    next    null    
    obj null    
    replyTo null    
    target  IncomingHandler  (id=830031033176)  
    what    0   
    when    180369888
```

Below is my worker thread's handleMessage().  Specifically, I instantiated a HandlerThread as my worker thread and bound it's getLooper() to my worker thread Handler.

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

    // If this is a Runnable then I need to call my method.
    // This next line is a hack to test for Runnable.
    // I would like to know how to inspect this Runnable
    if (0 == msg.arg2 && 0 == msg.arg1 && 0 == msg.what)
        incrementStateMachineBecauseRunnableStarted();

    // Determine which action to take
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021246/conveniently-map-between-enum-and-int-string
        switch (Cmd.values()[msg.what]) {

        case RECEIVE_NEW_LIST_EMPLOYEES:
            receiveNewListEmployees(msg);
            break;

        case UPDATE_ONE_EMPLOYEE_STATE:
            updateOneEmployeeState(msg);
            break;

        default:
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "unexpected message.";
            break;
}
```

This is how I enqueue my Runnable (I run this code on my worker thread, so it is sending a message to itself, to be processed later in `handleMessage(Message msg)`):

```
            // Create a new Runnable for this employee
            PostUpdate update = new PostUpdate(employee);
            // Post this Runnable with a sort delay
            postDelayed(update, WAIT_BEFORE_PUSH_MS);
```

... and this is how I enqueue my Messages (from another thread):

```
                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                msg.what = Cmd.RECEIVE_NEW_LIST_EMPLOYEES.ordinal();
                msg.arg1 = 77;  // deliberately inserting debug value
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList(Cmd.RECEIVE_NEW_LIST_EMPLOYEES.toString(), mEmployees);
                msg.setData(bundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

Finally, my Runnable:

```
private class PostUpdate implements Runnable {

    private final Employee mEmployee;

    public PostUpdate(Employee employee) {
        mEmployee = employee;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Post update through network to MySql server
        mDao.setState(mEmployee);
    }
}
```

Comment: I should also mention that I have assigned a value of non-zero to arg1 of _every_ message that I enqueue to be sure that I am not misinterpreting this Runnable as a "message".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My conclusion from using the debugger and inspecting the elements is that you cannot determine in handleMessage() whether a message or a runnable is being processed.

I found empirically (through elimination) that all my Runnables had a msg.what == 0 when I set all my messages to have msg.what to be something other than 0.  Use with care!